# Who should be credited for VLQ and zig-zag encoding?

Tags: protocol-buffers, zigzag-encoding

I have designed a (rather simple) network protocol which relies heavily on [VLQ-coded integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity) and [zig-zag coding](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Compression/Coding#ZigZag_encoding) (as described by the [Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding)). I learned about these techniques on the Internet and they felt quite obvious to me. However, now I want to compose an Internet-Draft describing my protocol, and it seems ridiculous to reference Wikipedia articles in a normative document.

Does somebody know a well-recognized publication, describing VLQ and zig-zag coding? Who is their original inventor?